# Eclipse RCP Application Export Application Could Not be Found in The Registry Error

Tags: eclipse, export, rcp

I've been facing this problem for days and unfortunately I couldn't find the proper solution on the internet.
I followed the instructions on  [this tutorial](http://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/#more-132)  to build a RCP application.I successfully built my application and got it running inside of the eclipse. Now, after importing my application using eclipse product export wizard in the .product file, I get a runtime error and my log file looks like this:

```
!SESSION 2014-09-26 20:49:27.654 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_60-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState -keyring /Users/mac/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState -keyring /Users/mac/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 20:49:32.759
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "test.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this issue? 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Make sure that all your plugins or features are listed in the .product file dependencies. Make sure that everything needed by your plugins is listed in the build.properties file for each plugin.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm pretty sure that all the required plugins are added in the dependencies because I followed the tutorial and I've added all plugins. What files should be included in the build.properties? Now my plugin.xml file and my Application.e4xmi file are included but none of the files in my src folder is included, such as Application.java. Should I include them too?